# Valgrind memory test error in C. Memory leak issue

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, cs50

I honestly don't know how to explain this but there's a memory leak in my code. The code passes all tests except for this one. The function is an unload function that unloads a dictionary from memory.

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        node *head = table[i];
        node *cursor = head;
        node *tmp = head;
        
        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = cursor;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function loads the dictionary:

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if (file == NULL) return false;
    
    while (fscanf(file,"%s",word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) return false;
        strcpy(n->word,word);
        n->next = NULL;
        
        int hash_index = hash(word);
        if (table[hash_index] == NULL)
        {
            table[hash_index] = n;
        }
        else 
        {
            n->next = table[hash_index];
            table[hash_index] = n;
        }
        total++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it is possible, it would be helpful to see all the malloc calls as well.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov Sorry, i have editted the post to show the load function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i forgot to close the file!

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if (file == NULL) return false;
    
    while (fscanf(file,"%s",word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) return false;
        strcpy(n->word,word);
        n->next = NULL;
        
        int hash_index = hash(word);
        if (table[hash_index] == NULL)
        {
            table[hash_index] = n;
        }
        else 
        {
            n->next = table[hash_index];
            table[hash_index] = n;
        }
        total++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When i use valgrind on a program with enough debug information valgrind tells where the memory leak is caused, in this case it would tell that the line where `fopen()` is called causes the leak (and all the functions `fopen()` calls to alloc space and the call tree before your `load()` function). Which debug flags do you use for your compiler? Use at least `-g` and disable or minimize the optimizer. https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Comment: OT: If you can write the functions so they getting a pointer to the `struct`'a and arrays they need to initialize and do not use `static` or global data. In this case, `table` should be given to this functions with a pointer, so you have later the possibility to use it for different dictionaries and you do not have problems when you later want to add multithreading or when the code is used in a library.